# Amiga File Manager with keyboard navigation

Tags: amiga, software-recommendation

Is there a file manager for Amiga OS 3.x, something like Directory Opus but keyboard-driven, which feels more like Midnight Commander or Total Commander, where all the navigation is done by keyboard rather than mouse?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[MCAmiga](http://eab.abime.net/showthread.php?t=102471) fits the bill, it’s pretty much Midnight Commander for the Amiga and uses the keyboard extensively.

[image: MCAmiga 0.8 screenshot showing the keyboard shortcuts]

Comment: Also, all mouse movements can be done via keyboard, but it's a pain sometimes.